# Как через Python скачивать ZIP или RAR архивы по ссылке?

Tags: python, url, download

Как через Python скачивать ZIP или RAR архивы по ссылке, установить в нужную директорию.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например через `requesrs`:

```
import requests
import zipfile
import os


def get_zip(url: str, path: str, filename: str):
    """
    :param url: Url файла, который надо скачать
    :param path: Путь до директории, в которую надо скачать файл
    :param filename: Имя файла
    """
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), "wb") as file:
        response = requests.get(url)
        file.write(response.content)


def unpack(path_to_zip: str, outpath: str):
    """
    :param path_to_zip: Путь до архива
    :param outpath: Путь до директории, в которую надо распаковать файл
    """
    file = zipfile.ZipFile(file=path_to_zip)
    file.extractall(outpath)


get_zip("https://www.sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-doc-3370000.zip", "C:/Users/Dmitry", "test.zip")
unpack("test.zip", "test")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Можете уточнить, как выбрать директорию скачивания архива?

Comment: Я немного изменил код. В `get_zip` указываете url до архива; путь до директории,  в которую надо скачать; имя файла, под которым его сохранить